# Retrieving SQL Server float with C# sqldatareader

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve the exact value that I see in the database.

The database column type is float. The database is not mine and I cannot change its type or anything. In the database, I have the value 0.1, but when I read it with SqlDataReader.GetDouble it returns something like 0.09999.....98.

I also tried using GetValue and then manually converting to double, but still no difference.

I also cant use static rounding because while this value is 0.1 in the database and is read as 0.09...98, there are some values that have a lot more decimals. F.e. there is a value 0.0151515151515152 which with GetDouble is being read as 0.015151515151515148

Comment: when using floating point arithmetic, thinking in terms of "the exact value" is inherently a mistake; you could *try* `GetDecimal`, but frankly: the data storage sounds simply wrong; no amount of "I cannot change its type or anything" limitations can fix that. In particular, `0.1` [does not exist in floating point](https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/), so I wonder if when you say "the exact value that I see in the database", whether what you mean is "when I use a UI tool, it is rounding the value to something that it actually isn't"

Comment: Adding on to the comment by @MarcGravell, executing `SELECT CAST(0.1 AS float);` in SSMS shows a result of 0.1. Run the same query with SQLCMD (`sqlcmd -Q "SELECT CAST(0.1 AS float);"`) and the result is 0.10000000000000001. These tools converted the actual binary float structure stored in the database into a decimal string for display purposes.